# Query rollbacked with new syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am inserting a record in Order table using new hash syntax but It gets rolled back but when I use associative array index it commits and inserts record in database. How is it working?

```
Order.create(status: 1, payment_intent: 'sada', amount_total: 10, user_id:100)
```

It Begin and then rollback

```
Order.create(:status =>1, :payment_intent => 'sada', :amount_total => 10, :user_id=>1)
```

It Begin and then commit.

Comment: If the record gets rolled back then the record shouldn't been in the database. If it is in the database and the record is being created and is shown in the database, what's the issue here. The only difference I see between those two outputs is the `user_id`

Would it be possible to get more explanation and get some more code examples?

Comment: user id is static in this case and not a point to worry about Only concern is that why is one is committing and other isn't

Comment: Without looking at more code, I won't be able to give you an explanation. How are orders created?